# "ValueError: 'PySide6.QtGui.QPainter.drawText' called with wrong argument values" even though the arguments seem right

Tags: python, pyside, pyside6

MRE:

```py
from PySide6 import QtWidgets as qtw
from PySide6 import QtGui as qtg
from PySide6 import QtCore as qtc


class Delegate(qtw.QAbstractItemDelegate):
    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        text = index.model().data(
            index, qtc.Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole
        )

        text_rect = qtc.QRect(
            option.rect.left(),
            option.rect.top(),
            option.rect.width(),
            200
        )

        painter.drawText(text_rect, 0, text, text_rect)

    def sizeHint(self, option, index):
        return qtc.QSize(200, 200)


class Model(qtc.QAbstractListModel):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self._texts = ["text" for _ in range(10)]

    def rowCount(self, _) -> int:
        return 10

    def data(self, index, role):
        if not index.isValid():
            return None

        if role == qtc.Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole:
            return self._texts[index.row()]
        
        return None

class MainWindow(qtw.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        delegate = Delegate(self)
        self._model = Model()
        self._view = qtw.QListView(self)
        self._view.setModel(self._model)
        self._view.setItemDelegate(delegate)

        self.setCentralWidget(self._view)
        self.show()


app = qtw.QApplication()
mw = MainWindow()
app.exec()
```

Error:

```py
ValueError: 'PySide6.QtGui.QPainter.drawText' called with wrong argument values:
  PySide6.QtGui.QPainter.drawText(PySide6.QtCore.QRect(230, 10, 0, 200), 0, '', PySide6.QtCore.QRect(230, 10, 0, 200))
Found signature:
  PySide6.QtGui.QPainter.drawText(PySide6.QtCore.QRect, int, str, PySide6.QtCore.QRect)
```

One of the signatures I get on VSCode for `painter.drawText`:

```py
def drawText(r: PySide6.QtCore.QRect, flags: int, text: str, br: PySide6.QtCore.QRect) -> None
```

The provided signatures and the passed arguments match, don't they? Could this be a bug in PySide6?
The code causing the error is in the `paint` method in the `Delegate` class.

Comment: Looks like a bug.. try using only `painter.drawText(text_rect, 0 ,text)`

Comment: @ניר that by itself works. However, I want to make use of the `boundingRect` parameter as well.

Comment: Yeah, as I said it looks like a bug. It doesn't work on pyqt as well.

Comment: Try substituting `0` with `qtc.Qt.AlignmentFlag(0)`.

Comment: @musicamante nope, doesn't work: `TypeError: 'PySide6.QtGui.QPainter.drawText' called with wrong argument types:  PySide6.QtGui.QPainter.drawText(QRect, AlignmentFlag, str, QRect)`

Comment: Then it's probably a bug (caused by the conversion of the flag, since it can accept flags of different types in C++). Does it work with a "normal" flag, like `Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter`?

Comment: @musicamante, nope, it's the same error as with `qtc.Qt.AlignmentFlag(0)`.

Comment: same issue here, any update OP?